# Converting TIMESTAMP to DATE with respect to timezone

Tags: oracle, timezone

I was inspecting how are DATEs stored in database. Consider the following statement:

```
SELECT
CAST (to_timestamp_tz('2018-12-05T10:00:00+01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE) AS PRAGUE_TIME,
CAST (to_timestamp_tz('2018-12-05T10:00:00+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE) AS GMT_TIME
FROM DUAL
```

Results in:

```
PRAGUE_TIME          GMT_TIME
2018-12-05 10:00:00  2018-12-05 10:00:00
```

The times are the same, despite one being created from a +1 timezone offset. Just to be sure, I added further conversion to string:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(CAST (to_timestamp_tz('2018-12-05T10:00:00+01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS PRAGUE_TIME,
TO_CHAR(CAST (to_timestamp_tz('2018-12-05T10:00:00+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') AS DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS GMT_TIME
FROM DUAL


PRAGUE_TIME          GMT_TIME
2018-12-05 10:00:00  2018-12-05 10:00:00
```

Same results. So how can I convert `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE` without loosing the timezone information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I convert `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE` without loosing the timezone information?

You cannot.

- A `DATE` only has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components.
- A `TIMESTAMP` has all those components plus nanoseconds and optionally time zone or time zone offset components.

If you convert from a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` then you will lose the information that the `DATE` cannot store.

What you can do is convert all the `TIMESTAMP`s to the same time zone using, for example, `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`:

```
SELECT CAST( TIMESTAMP '2018-12-05 10:00:00+01:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE )
         AS PRAGUE_TIME_AS_UTC,
       CAST( TIMESTAMP '2018-12-05 10:00:00+00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE )
         AS GMT_TIME_AS_UTC
FROM   DUAL
```

**Results**:

```
|   PRAGUE_TIME_AS_UTC |      GMT_TIME_AS_UTC |
|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2018-12-05T09:00:00Z | 2018-12-05T10:00:00Z |
```